# How to turn off auto replacement in Emacs Speaks Statistics for R

Tags: emacs, r, ess

In `Emacs Speaks Statistics` for `R`, how can the auto replacement of `_` with `<-` be turned off?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To stop this smart behaviour, add `(ess-toggle-underscore nil)` to your .emacs after `ess-site` has been loaded.

Answer (score 3):

What rcs said. But pressing _ again will turn the "<-" into "_" when you need it. So, when you need an underscore, just press it twice.