# How to stop emacs from replacing underbar with <- in ess-mode

Tags: r, emacs, ess

`ess-mode` is "Emacs speaks statistics." This mode is useful for editing programs for R or Splus (two separate statistics packages).

In my buffer, when ever I type `_` the character is replaced with `<-`, which is very frustrating.  Is there an emacs lisp statement to turn off this behavior?

emacs: 22.1.1
ess-mode release (unknown)

Comment: Duplicate - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816238/how-to-turn-off-auto-replacement-in-emacs-speaks-statistics-for-r

Comment: If you use `underscore_case` in the mix of naming conventions in R, (see https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012/RJ-2012-018/RJ-2012-018.pdf ) it is quite irritating.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From [ESS's manual](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html) (look under "Changes/New Features in 5.2.0"):

> ESS[S]: Pressing underscore ("_") once inserts " <- " (as before); pressing underscore twice inserts a literal underscore. To stop this smart behaviour, add "(ess-toggle-underscore nil)" to your .emacs after ess-site has been loaded

Comment: Just to be explicit, `(require 'ess-site)` should precede `(ess-toggle-underscore nil)` in .emacs or .emacs.d/init.el .

Answer (score 5):

Since the feature is useful. You can assign it to other key which is less used by you in R it will automatically unassign it from underscore. I personally assign it to `";"` by adding following line in .emacs file.

```
(setq ess-smart-S-assign-key ";")
```

My version of emacs is 24.3 All-in-one installation file by Vincent Goulet.(Installed on windows 7)

hope this helps

**Edit**
In emacs 25.2 above do not work instead add following in the .emacs file

```
(setq ess-smart-S-assign-key ";")
(ess-toggle-S-assign nil)
(ess-toggle-S-assign nil)
```

Comment: This stopped the problem of underscore replacement, but when I press ";" it doesn't make a "<-"...?

Comment: It makes `<-` in my version of emacs on windows 7. Is your any different?

Comment: Over the years, there has been [significant](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/584) ... [discussion](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/558) ... resulting in [commit ed048d3](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/commit/ed048d32be45b2a22fbe4d1c192cfdd7f367864b), with name-changes and some new default behavior. Most `*-smart-*` vars/funs are deprecated/deleted, now there is `ess-insert-S-assign` and optionally `ess-cycle-assignment`.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-small-customization-of-ess/ and
[How to change smart assign key ("_" to "<-") binding in ESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404278/how-to-change-smart-assign-key-to-binding-in-ess)

To assign ":" to "<-" and to stop the assignment of underscore (underbar) "_" to  "<-" put the following in .emacs (yes, the repeated line is correct)

```
(setq ess-smart-S-assign-key ":")
(ess-toggle-S-assign nil)
(ess-toggle-S-assign nil)
(ess-toggle-underscore nil) ; leave underscore key alone!
```

Comment: an explanation of why the duplicate line is necessary would be helpful.

Comment: According to the cited source: "The first call clears the default `ess-smart-S-assign' assignment and the second line re-assigns it to the customized setting."

Answer (score 3):

A more recent version which seemed to work for me, and is a lot less verbose (you essentially keep normal underscores, but can set your own key for this smart behaviour!):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;")  (lambda () (interactive) (insert " <- ")))
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)
```

Insert your shortkey choice instead of `C-;`.

Answer (score 2):

Like Michał Marczyk and [this R mailing list thread](http://grokbase.com/t/r/ess-help/11av89kfvh/ess-shift-underline-produces) suggested, add this line to `~/.emacs`:

```
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)
```

Then reload it with `M-x load-file` and type `~/.emacs`.

**But** if you load the file again, e.g. if you add another customization, then it toggles it back to the original state. So toggle it twice, the first one forcing it to the default:

```
(ess-toggle-underscore t)
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)
```

That being said, I like Drummermean's solution better, but it also reverts back to default if you add it to `~/.emacs` and load it twice. So force a toggle to the default before:

```
(ess-toggle-underscore t)
(global-set-key (kbd "M--")  (lambda () (interactive) (insert " <- ")))
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)
```

I bound the smart assignment to `Opt-[minus]` like `RStudio` (on a Mac).

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up on @mmorin answer. To set keybinding for the assignment operator the same way as in Rstudio add the following in your `.emacs` file

```
(ess-toggle-underscore t)
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "M--") (lambda () (interactive) (just-one-space 1) (insert "<-") (just-one-space 1)))
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map (kbd "M--") (lambda () (interactive) (just-one-space 1) (insert "<-") (just-one-space 1)))
```