# Emacs ESS polymode: double quotes turn to umlauts

Tags: r, emacs, knitr, ess

I just switched to Emacs + ESS for R programming, and am using the [newest bundle (24.3)](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/windows/) from Vincent Goulet.

I wanted a good environment for `knitr` and .Rmd files, so I installed `polymode` from MELPA. I also have the `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown+r-mode))` in my .emacs file.

When I started editing .Rmd files in `polymode`, I ran into an annoying behaviour. Inside R code blocks, but not outside, double double quotes `""` turn into umlauts `¨`, and double quotes + character, e.g. `"a` turn into characters with umlauts, `ä`. I'm guessing itmight have something to do with LaTeX and displaying umlauts, but have no idea on how to turn this behaviour off.

Is there some way to disable autoreplacing of double quotes, the same way you can [disable replacing the underscore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531372/how-to-stop-emacs-from-replacing-underbar-with-in-ess-mode)

Comment: What command does Emacs say is associated with `"`? You can get Emacs to show this with `C-h k "`.

Comment: Do you see this in .R files as well? I had similar problems with international keyboard setup sometimes, but they show everywhere, not just in emacs. Configuring the keyboard settings solves it for me.

Comment: I had to re-install Emacs and the behaviour disappeared. It might've been a keyboard issue, as my keyboard locale has been switching inexplicably, but I guess we'll never know :/

Comment: It sounds like a keyboard issue. I had been using ENG - INTL and experienced that issue. I switched to another keyboard layout (ENG - AUS) and the problem went away.