# How to change smart assign key ("_" to "<-") binding in ESS

Tags: r, emacs, key-bindings, ess

In emacs ESS, how do I correctly change the keybinding for ess-smart-S-assign?

What I tried is adding

```
(custom-set-variables
    '(ess-smart-S-assign-key ":"))
```

to my `.emacs`, but that made weird things happen: When I press `:`, just a normal `:` appears. On the other hand, pressing `_` once yields `<-` as usual, whereas pressing `_` a second time then converts this to `:`.
The desired behavior would be to be able to use `_` as a normal key, with `:` being converted to `<-`.

I am using the official emacs 24.3 for windows and the latest development version of ESS (14.06).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the docstring for `ess-smart-S-assign-key`:

```lisp
Documentation:
Key used by `ess-smart-S-assign'. By default bound to
underscore, but can be set to any key. If this key is customized,
you must add

 (ess-toggle-S-assign nil)
 (ess-toggle-S-assign nil)

after the line that sets the customization and evaluate these
lines or reboot emacs. The first call clears the default
`ess-smart-S-assign' assignment and the second line re-assigns
it to the customized setting.
```

So: put this in your `.emacs` file to get the desired behavior:

```
(setq ess-smart-S-assign-key ":")
(ess-toggle-S-assign nil)
(ess-toggle-S-assign nil)
```

Kind of ugly, but it works.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the hint! Should've found that myself, though. I just hope this will help others having the same problem, as I did not find anything really related on google.

Comment: This solves the issue both for R scripts and for R interactive process, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but the following did:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;")  (lambda () (interactive) (insert " <- ")))
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)
```

Insert your shortkey choice instead of `C-;`.

Comment: this changes binding in all modes

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is

```
(eval-after-load "ess-mode" '(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-;") "<-"))
(eval-after-load "ess-mode" '(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map (kbd "C-;") "<-"))
```

This allows to restrict the binding change to ess-mode. Note that the second line defines the binding for the inferior R process.